# What is a Flawless Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

*This puzzle is based off the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) and [What is a Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20phrase%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) and their spin-off [What is a Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) series.*

---

*An entry into the [20th fortnightly topic challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/fortnightly-topic-challenge-20-pattern?cb=1).*

---

## Main puzzle:

| Flawless Words™ | Non-Flawless Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| CADDIE | GOLFER |
| DOG | CAT |
| EFFACE | APPEAR |
| HIDE | SEEK |
| MAGE | FIRE |
| BEAR | WOLF |
| DEICE | WATER |
| GAME | WORK |
| HEAL | HARM |
| TEA | PEA |
| ALGAE | OCEAN |

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a Flawless Word™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

Here is a CSV:

```
Flawless Words™,Non-Flawless Words™
CADDIE,GOLFER
DOG,CAT
EFFACE,APPEAR
HIDE,SEEK
MAGE,FIRE
BEAR,WOLF
DEICE,WATER
GAME,WORK
HEAL,HARM
TEA,PEA
ALGAE,OCEAN
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Flawless Word™ on its own.

These are not the only examples of Flawless Word™ (or non-Flawless Word™), more can be found.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A Flawless Word™ is a word that

> its letters add up to 26.

Take the first word:

CADDIE

> 3 +1 +4 +4 +9 +5 = 26.

The second:

DOG

> 4 + 15 +7 = 26

EFFACE

> 5 + 6 +6 +1 +3 +5 = 26

They are probably called 'Flawless' because that's

> the number of letters in the alphabet.

Comment: HOW DO YOU GET THESE SO FAST

Comment: @greenturtle3141 I always try those an these TM puzzles.

Comment: @Mithrandir - Wow! How is my answer works here as well :D +1 for you anyway. Not sure which one is the ONE!

Comment: @Mithrandir PEE is my mistake... I am gonna update it...

Comment: @Mithrandir yes, your answer is the one that I was looking for :)

Comment: @Techidiot In your answer, you use (27-n) instead of n for the nth letter, so for a word with k letters, you'll get sum 27k-S where this answer gets S. And S=26 implies that modulo 9, we have 27k-S = -26 = 1 (mod 9), which is why your pattern works. But not the other way around: you can get sums (27k-S) that are 1 mod 9 without S being exactly 26: it can be any number that is 8 mod 9 (such as 8, 17, 26, 35, 44,...).

Answer (score 8):

The Flawless words are those -

> Which when summed to one digit gives answer as "1". Where alphabets are assigned values from A=26, B=25...

Examples -

> **CADDIE** = 24 + 26 + 23 + 23 + 18 + 22 = 136 = 1+3+6 = 10 = 1+0 = 1
>  **DOG** = 23 + 12 + 20 = 55 = 5+5 = 10 = 1+0 = 1
>  **EFFACE** = 22 + 21 + 21 + 26 + 24 + 22 = 136 = 1+3+6= 10 = 1+0 = 1
>  **HIDE** = 19 + 18 + 23 + 22 = 82 = 8 + 2 = 10 = 1+0 = 1

Non-Flawless words do not follow this property

> **GOLFER** = 20 + 12 + 15 + 21 + 22 + 9 = 99 = 9+9 = 18 = 1+8 = 9
>  **CAT** = 24 + 26 + 7 = 57 = 7+5=12 = 1+2 = 3
>  **APPEAR** = 26 + 11 + 11 + 22 + 26 + 9 = 105 = 1+0+5 = 6
>  **SEEK** = 8 + 22 + 22 + 16 = 68 = 6+8 = 14 = 1+5 = 6
>  **FIRE** = 21 + 18 + 9 + 22 = 70 = 7+0 = 7

These may be called Flawless because,

> flawless is a synonym of entire and word **ENTIRE** follows the same rule. Other reason could be, number 1 is considered as **PERFECT** and perfect is nothing but Flawless.

Comment: PEE is my mistake... I am gonna update it...

Comment: @Oray- Great then! Also accept the answer which was on your mind considering that the question has two solutions now.